# Specify header locations for C compiler (compiling R code with emscripten)

Tags: javascript, c, r, emscripten

I'm relatively inexperienced compiling C code. Nevertheless, I'm trying to use emscripten to compile an algorithm from the R source code into JavaScript. The function is in a file called `pf.c` [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/pf.c)

Naively, I have just gone into the `src` directory and tried:

```
emcc nmath/pf.c
```

This results in:

```
In file included from nmath/pf.c:25:
nmath/nmath.h:38:10: fatal error: 'Rconfig.h' file not found
#include <Rconfig.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
ERROR    root: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

I know where this header is:

```
$ find . -name "Rconfig.h"
./gnuwin32/fixed/h/Rconfig.h
```

My immediate question is, how do I tell the compiler where this header exists?
I'd like to end up with a `pf` function in JavaScript. Any insight into this idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Use `-I` to add to the include search path.

```
emcc nmath/pf.c -Ignuwin32/fixed/h/
```

Regarding the overall idea... sounds weird, I don't know.